# pandas pivot_table: can I display sub-totals in the output?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

Suppose I have a very simple dataframe, like so:

```
data={"Label": (1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3), "Value": ("a","b","b","b","c","a","b","a","c")}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
```

I can generate a pivot table as follows, by writing `pd.pivot_table(testdf,index=["Label", "Value"],values=["Value"],aggfunc=len)`:

```
________________________
|Label | Value | Count |
|------+-------+-------|
|  1   |   a   |   1   |
|      |   b   |   2   |
|  2   |   a   |   1   |
|      |   b   |   2   |
|      |   c   |   1   |
|  3   |   a   |   1   |
|      |   c   |   1   |
|------+-------+-------|
```

Is there any way to replicate Excel pivot table functionality, with the top-level aggregates included?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find an explicit equivalent in pandas, but you can always chain multiple functions together. I'll give a `groupby` example:

```
import pandas as pd

data={"Label": (1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3), "Value": ("a","b","b","b","c","a","b","a","c")}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)

df["Top_Level_Counts"] = df.groupby("Label").transform("count")
df["Counts"] = df.groupby(["Label","Value"]).transform("count")
print(df)

   Label Value  Top_Level_Counts  Counts
0      1     a                 3       1
1      1     b                 3       2
2      1     b                 3       2
3      2     b                 4       2
4      2     c                 4       1
5      2     a                 4       1
6      2     b                 4       2
7      3     a                 2       1
8      3     c                 2       1
```

Or a one liner like this (my preference):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(data = data)
        .assign(Top_Level_Counts = lambda x:x.groupby("Label").transform("count"))
        .assign(Counts = lambda x:x.groupby(["Label","Value"]).transform("count"))
        ).set_index(["Label","Value"])

print(df)

             Top_Level_Counts  Counts
Label Value
1     a                     3       1
      b                     3       2
      b                     3       2
2     b                     4       2
      c                     4       1
      a                     4       1
      b                     4       2
3     a                     2       1
      c                     2       1
```